# same ascx file with javascript used multiple times on the same page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

we have an ascx file with some javascript on it that has some variables and functions defined.

We need to add this ascx control twice on the same page and the problem we have is that the variables get overwritten by the last instance of the ascx control. We thought about prefixing the javascript variables with some unique identifier in c# but then the code becomes unreadable

i.e.  var <%=ID%>variablename = “”;

any ideas on how I could get this to work without the variables getting overwritten?

EDIT:
I'm basically having the issue described on this website, but my js has multiple variables and functions, so this approach leaves my page full of mixed up js and c# and makes is unreadable

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Issue-JavaScript-in-WebUserControl-not-working-when-used-multiple-times-on-same-page.aspx

Comment: Put the required variables in to `data-*` attributes on the elements and then use a single instance of the script which reads those attributes from the element which raised the event.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't follow...could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: I'd like to, but you've not really given me anything to work with, which is why I gave you an outline of the general pattern. If you could post your HTML/JS code I can give you a more concrete example.

Comment: Why not set the server control ID's to static ID's, and your variables will make more sense then.